# Exporting crosstab query results to Excel from within MS Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, export

I've been trying with limited success to export a crosstab query result set to Excel using Access 2003. Occasionally, the export works correctly, and Excel shows with no errors. Other times, using the exact same query parameters, I get a 3190 error - too many fields. I am using the TransferSpreadsheet option in a macro that is called from VB code.

The macro has the following parameters:
Transfer type: Export
Spreadsheet type: Microsoft Excel 8-10
Table Name: (this is my query name)
File Name: (Excel output file, which exists in the directory)
Has Field Names: Yes

The query should not produce any more than 14 columns worth of information, so the Excel 255 col limit should not be a problem. Also,the data in the database is not changing during the time I am querying, so the same query will produce the same result set.

One of the only solutions I have read on the net thus far is to close the recordset before running the macro, but this is hit or miss.

Your thoughts/help are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you exporting to the same Excel file each time? Does the crosstab return a variable number of columns? And, just vaguely possible, have you installed sp3 and the sp3 hotfix?

Answer (score 2):

I've got one working as an MS Access Macro.
It uses an OutputTo Action with:

- Object Type=Query
- Object Name=[WhateverQueryName]
- Output Format=MicrosoftExcel(*.xls)
- Auto Start=No
- (all the rest blank)

I hate using Macros in MS Access (it feels unclean), but perhaps give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to make use of a little vba rather than stick exclusively with macros, the following might help you. This module takes any sql you throw at it and exports it to a defined location in an excel worksheet. After the module are two examples of it's use, one to create a completely new workbook, one which opens an existing one. If you not confident with using SQL just create the query you want, save it and then supply "SELECT * FROM [YourQueryName]" to the Sub as the QueryString parameter.

```
Sub OutputQuery(ws As excel.Worksheet, CellRef As String, QueryString As String, Optional Transpose As Boolean = False)

    Dim q As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i, j As Integer

    i = 1

    q.Open QueryString, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly


    If Transpose Then
        For j = 0 To q.Fields.Count - 1
            ws.Range(CellRef).Offset(j, 0).Value = q(j).Name
            If InStr(1, q(j).Name, "Date") > 0 Or InStr(1, q(j).Name, "DOB") > 0 Then
                ws.Range(CellRef).Offset(j, 0).EntireRow.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            End If
        Next

        Do Until q.EOF
            For j = 0 To q.Fields.Count - 1
                ws.Range(CellRef).Offset(j, i).Value = q(j)
            Next
            i = i + 1
            q.MoveNext
        Loop
    Else
        For j = 0 To q.Fields.Count - 1
            ws.Range(CellRef).Offset(0, j).Value = q(j).Name
            If InStr(1, q(j).Name, "Date") > 0 Or InStr(1, q(j).Name, "DOB") > 0 Then
                ws.Range(CellRef).Offset(0, j).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            End If
        Next

        Do Until q.EOF
            For j = 0 To q.Fields.Count - 1
                ws.Range(CellRef).Offset(i, j).Value = q(j)
            Next
            i = i + 1
            q.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    q.Close

End Sub
```

Example 1:

```
Sub Example1()
    Dim ex As excel.Application
    Dim wb As excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As excel.Worksheet

    'Create workbook
    Set ex = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ex.Visible = True
    Set wb = ex.Workbooks.Add
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    OutputQuery ws, "A1", "Select * From [TestQuery]"
End Sub
```

Example 2:

```
Sub Example2()
    Dim ex As excel.Application
    Dim wb As excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As excel.Worksheet

    'Create workbook
    Set ex = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ex.Visible = True
    Set wb = ex.Workbooks.Open("H:\Book1.xls")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("DataSheet")

    OutputQuery ws, "E11", "Select * From [TestQuery]"
End Sub
```

Hope that's of some use to you.

Comment: I tried your code and it didn't actually work on a cross tab query for me.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to append the query to a table first and then export that.

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
 DoCmd.OpenQuery "TempTable-Make" 
 DoCmd.RunSQL "DROP TABLE TempTable" 
 ExportToExcel()
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

TempTable-Make is a make-table query based on the crosstab.

[Here](http://www.excelguru.ca/node/23) is an appropriate ExportToExcel function you can use.

Answer (score 0):

The following code exports queries using the function in excel that was specifically designed to import recordsets `CopyFromRecordset`. Note that field names need to be added as this function only grabs the actual data. This code works even on crosstab queries.

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Method : MoveQueryToWorksheet
' Author : ROLU
' Date   : 09.05.2018
' Purpose: Moves queries to specific worksheet in an Excel Workbook
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function MoveQueryToWorksheet(wkb As Excel.Workbook, wks As Variant, strSQL As Variant) As Boolean
On Error GoTo MoveQueryToWorksheet_Error

'Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
'rs.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Dim rs
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

Dim lCol As Long
For lCol = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    wkb.Worksheets(wks).Cells(1, lCol + 1).Value = rs.Fields(lCol).Name
Next lCol
wkb.Worksheets(wks).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

'Close out and clean
Set rs = Nothing
MoveQueryToWorksheet = True

    Exit Function

MoveQueryToWorksheet_Error:
On Error GoTo 0
Set rs = Nothing
MoveQueryToWorksheet = False

End Function
```